# JavaScript: Get the value of a dinamicly generated object

Tags: javascript, object, window

I know I can access the value of a user defined variable by composing its name like

```
window["myvariable"+1234]
```

What I don't know is how to access the value of inner properties. I want something like the following code, but that works:

```
//Suppose there is an object with user-generated property names like myCars.Ford.Focus.mileage and I need a function that reports the value of a certain property only when the content is not an empty string. So we create a function like
function squealProperty(maker,model,UDProp){
    if(window["myCars."+maker+"."+model+"."+UDProp+".length"] > 0){
        alert("User defined property inspector ("+UDProp+")="+window["myCars."+maker+"."+model+"."+UDProp]);
    };
};
```

In moments like this, I usually find answers to my prayers in "The Book"[1] but no luck this time. So I ask here.
[1] By "The Book" I mean "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide", 5th Edition. By David Flanagan

Comment: `MyCars[maker][model][UDProp].length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access the propertys as a single string when you access them with []. So you have to break them down. Also you code will break if you try to check all at one time, so you have to check just one "inner" property at every check.

```
function squealProperty(maker,model,UDProp){
    if(window["myCars"] && window["myCars"][maker] && window["myCars"][maker][model] && window["myCars"][maker][model][UDProp] && window["myCars"][maker][model][UDProp].length > 0){
        alert("User defined property inspector ("+UDProp+")="+window["myCars"][maker][model][UDProp]);
    };
};
```

Comment: Agh... a matter of syntax!
Tobbe! Do you use PayPal? Allow me to buy you a coffee!

Answer (score 1):

Access it in parts:

```
function squealProperty(maker,model,UDProp){
    var obj = window.myCars;
    if (obj && 
        (obj = obj[maker]) &&
        (obj = obj[model]) &&
        (obj = obj[UDProp]) ) {

        /* do something with obj */

    }  
}

var myCars = {maker: {model: {UDProp:[0,1,2,3]}}};
squealProperty('maker','model','UDProp'); // 4
```